# Iterating $f(x) = P \bmod x$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Take a prime number $P \ge 3$ and some integer $x \in [1, P-1]$. Let's consider a sequence of values $x = x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_k = 1$, where $x_{n+1} = P \bmod x_n$ and the first occurence of $1$ happens after $k$ iterations.

Are there any good lower bounds for such $k$? Since $x_{n+1} < x_n$, it is obviously $O(x)$. Exactly $x$ iterations can be reached using prime of form $P = k x! - 1$.

I tried some random values of $P$ up to $2^{25}$ and the maximum value of $k$ did not exceed $2 \log_2 P$. Can you prove it is always $O(\log P)$ or are there counterexamples?

Comment: Related (sort of): https://oeis.org/A177967

Comment: Possibly obvious:
All divisors of p-n, fail in less than n+2 steps, due to decreasing sequence, and remainder limitations. Using parity rules we can show that P being odd forces one of $odd* odd+even$ or $odd*even+odd$ The latter leads to the eventual 1. It's really the avoiding divisors of p-n that kills it. Prime starts have the longest possible stretch in theory. How many primes below P that are a prime distance away from P ? Highly composite numbers or primorials are possibly the forcers of lower bounds. They lead to the lowest number of coprime remainders.