# What is the asymptotic of $l_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, asymptotics

Suppose $n$ is some natural number. Consider the following recurrent sequence of natural numbers $(a_i)$:
$$a_{i+1} = n \% a_{i}$$
Here $\%$ stands for remainder. For example, if $n = 13$ and $a_0 = 7$, then the sequence is: 7, 6, 1, 0 (it stops, because $n \% 0$ is undefined).

It is not hard to see, that all such sequences are finite and stop at $0$. It follows from the fact that $0 \leq n \% a < a$. Let's denote the length of such sequence for given $n$ and $a_0$ length as $l(n, a_0)$.

Now consider, the sequence $l_n = \max\{l(n, a_0)| 1 \leq a_0 < n\}$. What is the asymptotics of $l_n$?

I used the following code to plot the values of $l_n$ for $n \leq 10000$:

```
r = []
for i in tqdm(range(1, 10001)):
    l = [0]
    for j in range(1, i):
        l.append(l[i%j] + 1)
    r.append(max(l))
plt.plot(r)
plt.show()
```

That is what I got:

[image]

On the plot it looks like $l_n = \Theta(\log(n))$, but I have no idea how to prove this.

Also note that $argmax_k l(n, k) \geq \frac{n}{2}$, because $l(n, n-k) = l(n, k) + 1$ $\forall k < \frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: How are $\pmod n$ and $\pmod {n+1}$ related ...

Comment: Maybe take a look at the $a_0$ for which this maximum is achieved at a few given values of $n$? If there's a pattern you might be able to compute $l(a_0,n)$ for specific values of $a_0$ and deduce a lower bound on $l_n$? For example, can you compute $l(F_m,F_{m+1})$, where $F_0,F_1,\ldots$ are the Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Also, what is your definition of $\Theta(\log n)$? Do you mean that there exist positive absolute constants $C,D,N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $C\cdot \log n \le l_n\le D\cdot \log n$?

Comment: @Mastrem, yes, $a_n = \Theta(f(n))$ means there exist positive absolute constants $C, D, N$, such that $\forall n \geq N$ we have $Cf(n) \leq a_n \leq Df(n)$.

Comment: I think this problem is incredibly hard and only a heuristic argument can be given. (Of course if we used $a_{i+1}:=a_{i-1}\%a_i$ it'd be a different story, because that's just the Euclidean algorithm) In what context did this problem come up?

Comment: Duplicate (not that it helps much, though): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2756510/iterating-fx-p-bmod-x